# Wordplay is Heavier Than Me

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *Usually, I am prepared, 
>  If only correctly designed; 
>  Otherwise I am impaired, 
>  Though once I am made, I am blind. 
>  
>  My travels remain unforeseen, 
>  By makers as well as the made. 
>  The wind is known to intervene, 
>  Explaining why I might have swayed. 
>  
>  A colour was much uninvited, 
>  For my classic is ever so white. 
>  After scrambling, you will be delighted, 
>  But at first kill the guest on the right. 
>  
>  Find the word near the burial ground, 
>  But count only half of the numeral. 
>  Put a spell on the word, not the sound, 
>  And the answer is there, not a funeral.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

This will be my last riddle for a couple of days, as school is very important and I need to keep up with the work due. Consequently, I have tried to make this riddle quite hard by using extensive wordplay. The first half talks a bit about the answer; the second half talks about the *directions*.

---

I have added a hint, because this riddle has proved to be a bit too difficult! $\ldots$ I then added a little bit more to the hint to make the answer less broad, but I still like all the answers anyway!

**Hint:**

> *$\verb|x|$ marks the spot, 
>  And the colour's nearly hot. 
>  
>  Is it treasure? No it's not. 
>  Closer to a slingshot.*

Comment: @JaredLovin thanks for the edit. I did not realise I made a typo :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you be

> a paper plane

Usually, I am prepared, 
If only correctly designed;

> The plane is ready to fly, if properly constructed.

Otherwise I am impaired,

> If the paper plane is not properly constructed, then it won't fly well.

Though once I am made, I am blind.

> A paper plane doesn't have eyes. Also, if you will, it doesn't have a view port/cockpit, so the imaginary paper pilot can't see..

My travels remain unforeseen,
By makers as well as the made.

> The paper plane does not know which way it will go, nor does the plane maker.

The wind is known to intervene, 
Explaining why I might have swayed.

> Wind can heavily influence the direction in which the plane flies.

A colour was much uninvited, 
For my classic is ever so white.

> paper is classically white

After scrambling, you will be delighted,
But in first kill the guest on the right.

> Take prepared and remove red to get prepa. Then scramble to get paper.

Find the word near the burial ground, 
But count only half of the numeral. 
Put a spell on the word, not the sound, 
And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> From the word "explaining", we only consider five letters (because x is the numeral for 10, so half is 5) of the word. So, we'll consider plain which is homophone for plane (satisfies putting a spell on the word and not the sound).

Hint:

> "X marks the spot": Indicates the word "explaining" in the riddle. "And the colour's nearly hot.": Red is usually used to indicate heat. Red is located in the words "prepared" and "impaired".

Comment: And this is where Bon Jovi sings, *"Woah, you're halfway there..."* :D

Comment: @user477343 how about now?

Comment: It is great! $100$ rep bounty coming up in $4$ hours :D

Comment: Lost my charger, computer died... but you still got the bounty in the end :)

Comment: Any reason for the ninja downvote, ninja?

Comment: I am confused; is this being referred to me or somebody else?

Comment: Someone else, sorry (idk who)

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, I say the same thing! Why would somebody downvote this beautiful answer?

Answer (score 6):

You are a

> Feather

Usually, I am prepared, 
If only correctly designed;

> Maybe that you can buy fake feathers.

Otherwise I am impaired, 
Though once I am made, I am blind.

> some feathers look like they have an eye on them but they can't see.

My travels remain unforeseen, 
By makers as well as the made.

> Birds and their travels.

The wind is known to intervene, 
Explaining why I might have swayed.

> Air resistance prevents it from falling normally.

A colour was much uninvited, 
For my classic is ever so white.

> Peacock VS. swan.

After scrambling, you will be delighted, 
But in first kill the guest on the right.

> ??

Find the word near the burial ground, 
But count only half of the numeral.

> Maybe dropped feathers otherwise I have no idea.

Put a spell on the word, not the sound, 
And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> If you switch the letters around and change one you get breathe.

The Title

> Light as a feather.

Comment: Great attempt! Unfortunately, that is not the answer. I will upvote when my voting limit is over. By the way, I will award you the $100$ rep bounty in my previous question before I accept your answer :D

Comment: Whether I liked it or not, I had to upvote — $6666$ is a *terrible* rep number. Lucky I liked your answer :D

Comment: @user477343 Why is that terrible? Often misunderstood.

Comment: @ManojKumar because it is close to the number of the beast... hahah, I am superstitious. I am that kind of guy that doesn't put new shoes on a table; doesn't open an umbrella inside a house; but likes to walk under a ladder :)

Comment: What can you do with his UserId then? :P

Answer (score 5):

You are an

> Envelope

Usually, I am prepared, 
If only correctly designed;

> You only send one if you correctly write down the address

Otherwise I am impaired, 
Though once I am made, I am blind.

> Once properly prepared, you can't see inside

My travels remain unforeseen, 
By makers as well as the made.

> The envelope makers don't know where they will be sent

The wind is known to intervene, 
Explaining why I might have swayed.

> Air mail can be diverted due to weather

A colour was much uninvited, 
For my classic is ever so white.

> Envelopes are usually white!

After scrambling, you will be delighted, 
But in first kill the guest on the right.

> The stamp (often a picture of a human, in the US attached on the right side) is cancelled before being taken to the destination

Find the word near the burial ground, 
But count only half of the numeral.

> No idea here

Put a spell on the word, not the sound, 
And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> Also, not sure. You spell the words in the address, and weddings would be the counterpart to funerals - weddings have invites in envelopes, funerals don't!

The Title

> Envelopes are light, often lighter than the letter inside them

Comment: Another very clever answer! But unfortunately, that is incorrect. However, this answer is the closest to the actual answer compared to all the others thus far, so... $(+1)$

Answer (score 4):

Just my guess, though I haven't got all the clues yet. I think you are

> an egg

Usually, I am prepared,

If only correctly designed;

Otherwise I am impaired,

> if an egg is cracked or somehow defective you don't cook it.

Though once I am made, I am blind.

> Once an egg is made, it's sealed.

My travels remain unforeseen,

By makers as well as the made.

> The hen doesn't know where its egg goes, and I guess neither does the egg.

The wind is known to intervene,

Explaining why I might have swayed.

> "Wind eggs" are eggs that are missing their yolk, or are otherwise defective (connotations vary).

A colour was much uninvited,

For my classic is ever so white.

> Many chicken eggs are white, and they're traditionally depicted as such.

After scrambling, you will be delighted,

> Scrambled eggs, of course!

But in first kill the guest on the right.

> No idea.

Find the word near the burial ground,

But count only half of the numeral.

Put a spell on the word, not the sound,

And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> This part seems to be instructions for the wordplay that will lead you to the answer, but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: Man, this site is *full* of clever minds! Very good try! But unfortunately that is not the answer. The last part, however, might be closest to the truth.... $(+1)$ ;D

Answer (score 4):

Am I a ...

> **COFFIN**

Usually, I am prepared,

> Coffins are generally prepared from wood.

If only correctly designed;

> Coffins are mostly designed in a certain shape, size and also the type of wood to be used.

Otherwise I am impaired,

> Without any design, I am just another piece of wood.

Though once I am made, I am blind.

> Once a coffin is made, they just close you and you can't see anything or it is blind to religion, caste or creed; anyone can use it irrespectively.

My travels remain unforeseen,

> Coffins can be used by anyone and it can be transported anywhere.

By makers as well as the made.

> The person who makes the coffin doesn't know to whom it is going to be made for. It could be himself!.

The wind is known to intervene,
Explaining why I might have swayed.

> Am not sure how to explain this part though.

A colour was much uninvited,

> Generally wood has it's own natural colour, so in olden days they wouldn't paint or colour the coffins.

For my classic is ever so white.

> Of late (19th or 20th century) they seem to have paint it white fully or decorate it inside with white cloth.

After scrambling, you will be delighted,

> Nowadays people plan their own funeral using funeral agencies who take care of this part for you. So you will be delighted after choosing from a range of coffins (size, shape and material).

But in first kill the guest on the right.

> Not sure about this one. I think this might refer to "[Hospitum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospitium)" or "[Guest right](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Guest_right)" (Game of Thrones). And inferring from this, it means that the funeral agency first has to wait for the client (guest) to die for the coffin to be used.

Find the word near the burial ground,

> You would mostly find coffins near the burial ground.

But count only half of the numeral.

> With the word ***C-O-F-F-I-N***, there are 6 letters, if you count only half then you have 3 letters that you could choose. The 1st part of ***COF*** doesn't make any sense, choosing the second half ***FIN*** makes good sense.

Put a spell on the word, not the sound,

> If you taken **FIN** from **COFFIN**, and then do a 3 letter word play for FIN, you would get a new word.

And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> The answer from the 3 letter wordplay would be ***END*** and it's self explanatory.

Comment: Nice try, especially regarding the wordplay part! However, the answer does not contain anything related to a funeral; and classic versions of your answer are not white, so unfortunately, that too is incorrect. I believe I made this riddle a bit too hard, and might need to give a hint, so I will do tomorrow. Either way, $(+1)$.

Comment: @user477343: Just a check, if I can answer another time for the same question in Puzzling SE? I have a couple of answers that could fit for this.

Comment: sure you can answer as many times as you want. If they fit, I’ll upvote; if one is the answer, I’ll accept :D

Answer (score 4):

New answer :

> Paper plane.

Usually, I am prepared,
If only correctly designed;
Otherwise I am impaired,
Though once I am made, I am blind.

> Paper planes are usually prepared but they fly only when they are correctly folded. Otherwise they won't fly. They can fly in any direction but they cannot see.

My travels remain unforeseen,
By makers as well as the made.
The wind is known to intervene,
Explaining why I might have swayed.

> The trajectory or flight of the plane remains unknown to everyone including the maker of the same. The wind sole decides the direction of the flight or it can simply knock it down and it will sway back to the ground.

A colour was much uninvited,
For my classic is ever so white.
After scrambling, you will be delighted,
But in first kill the guest on the right.

> Students often tear the pages from the notebooks to make planes which are mostly white. Most of the time the used pages which are scribbled all over used to make the plane.But in first we have to tear the page from the notebook which can be correlated to killing.

Find the word near the burial ground,
But count only half of the numeral.
Put a spell on the word, not the sound,
And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> Thanks to the author for the hint, The initial part of the answer which is paper is coming from "prepared" which is in the 1st paragraph. When we remove(kill) the color which is on the right the latter can be re-positioned  to form paper. Similarly is with the word "explaining" which has the 'x' marking the spot and if we find anagrams of the same there we get the 2nd part of the answer which is plane.

Hint: x marks the spot,
And the colour's nearly hot.

> Usually for the purpose of sport the children they mark a target on any board with an X and try to hit the same with the plane. (Not sure).

Title

> Paper Plane is lighter than wordplay used to make this puzzle :D

Comment: Think with words... for example, Rot13(gur jbeq "cercnerq" vf va gur svefg fragrapr, jvgu n pbybhe ba gur evtug bs gur jbeq. Trg evq bs gur pbybhe naq fpenzoyr gur erznvavat yrggref gb znxr nabgure jbeq, juvpu vf va gur nafjre. Abj, hfvat gur fnzr guvaxvat, svaq n jbeq va gur evqqyr gung pbagnvaf na "k", naq hfr gur pyhrf...)

Comment: In $10$ hours, I will be able to upvote (because of my daily voting limit). Although your answer is correct, a few of your reasonings are not quite, and so for that, I will award you a $50$ rep bounty after I have awarded the other bounty to @JaredLovin.

Comment: Dammit, it looks like after awarding a $100$ rep bounty, I can only award a $200+$ bounty after that... :\

Comment: yes.. that's what the rule is.. :) @user477343

Answer (score 4):

My try...

> You're an Arrow!

Usually, I am prepared If only correctly designed;
Otherwise I am impaired,
Though once I am made, I am blind.

> Archers are known to have their arrows prepared on the back. But you've to design an arrow in a right was, otherwise it won't be able to fly (impaired). an Arrow is also blind because the front of the arrow is always in the dark quiver

My travels remain unforeseen,
By makers as well as the made.
The wind is known to intervene,
Explaining why I might have swayed.

> Normally, no one can be too sure where an arrow will fly,not even the archer with 100% certainty. The wind obviously has a huge impact on the arrow, causing him to fail the target sometimes

A colour was much uninvited,
For my classic is ever so white.
After scrambling, you will be delighted,
But in first kill the guest on the right.

> As far as i can think of, the first arrows and bows were a very light color, almost white cause they were shaped out of ash-tree wood (very light brown) or the bones of animals (white). I might be wrong on the next part, but i kinda think this is a reference to Game of Thrones "Red wedding", where the guest "rights" are violated and the archers kill several important Starks such as Catelyn Stark, Robb Stark + wife

Find the word near the burial ground,
But count only half of the numeral.
Put a spell on the word, not the sound,
And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> Not sure what that means but i guess the "word" is the answer you're looking for. Many people for instance, searched in war for their beloved ones and found them with an arrow in the chest, thus having the answer.

x marks the spot,
And the colour's nearly hot

> classical hint. "X marks the Spot" is often the spot where trainees try to shoot into, when trying to improve their erchery skills. "The color's nearly hot" is a reference to the warm/hot color red, which is also a symbol for archery, for instance in Darts. The closer you get to the middle, the closer you get to the red spot.

Comment: This is not the answer, but it can pass as an alternative! I will award you a $50$ rep bounty if I can! I don't know how many bounties I can award on the same post, hahah :D

Comment: Dammit, it looks like after awarding a $100$ rep bounty, I can only award a $200+$ bounty after that... :\

Comment: No worries, dude :P Just keep making Puzzles, that'd make me happier than a 200+ reward!

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer :-

> A letter.

Usually, I am prepared,

If only correctly designed;

Otherwise I am impaired,

Though once I am made, I am blind.

> A letter is usually prepared using content related to the topic of the letter. But initially a draft of the same is designed/created. And if the content doesn't matches with the subject of the letter than it renders it useless.Moreover the correct format can be related to the designing part. A letter once completed is sealed inside a envelope and thus we can correlate it getting blind.

My travels remain unforeseen,
By makers as well as the made.
The wind is known to intervene,
Explaining why I might have swayed.

> A letter does not knows where it will be posted as the address is usually written on the envelope which is usually decided by the makers or writer of the letter. Sometimes we've seen that letters when kept in open that too unattended are blown away in windy weather which clearly explain them getting swayed off in air.

A colour was much uninvited,
For my classic is ever so white.
After scrambling, you will be delighted,
But in first kill the guest on the right.

> Usually in earlier times the traditional color format was black on white i.e. white page and black ink. But in late 90's kids starting using colored pages to write letters on. Not sure about the scrambling and killing part.

Find the word near the burial ground,
But count only half of the numeral.
Put a spell on the word, not the sound,
And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> Not sure about this part.

Comment: Good attempt! But unfortunately, that is not the answer. You might want to read the hint, as your reasoning for the "color" section is incorrect. The color is a specific one, hidden in the riddle itself! It is close though. Letters, envelopes... they are pretty close. $(+1)$

Comment: Well I'm thinking that it's a Rot13(tencu cncre) @user477343

Comment: That's not it either.... but Rot13(cncre) is the first word :D

Comment: Drafting the explanation for the same :) @user477343

Answer (score 3):

Would I be a ...

> **TREASURE MAP**

Usually, I am prepared,

> Generally a map is prepared on a piece of paper

If only correctly designed;

> You will have text, regions, areas, symbols, direction, scale and any specific location based information. In this case marked by the location of the treasure.

Otherwise I am impaired,

> If not marked with a treasure location (implicitly or explicitly), I am just another map.

Though once I am made, I am blind.

> If the treasure map is made, you are hiding the location of the treasure in the map. And to an ordinary person, it remains just another map. Or hiding in plain sight.

My travels remain unforeseen,
By makers as well as the made.

> Generally, with a treasure map, you would either hide the map or you might give the map to someone or hide it in plain sight, so that it is not easy to get it or you would want to get the treasure at a later stage. Also, you don't know when you might travel out there again to get the treasure back.

The wind is known to intervene,
Explaining why I might have swayed.

> To obtain the treasure, and provided you have found out where the treasure is, you would have to keep moving in all / certain directions using different transportation modes.

A colour was much uninvited,
For my classic is ever so white.

> Generally maps are made out of paper which is generally sepia / natural colour tone.
> But generally they make maps in white to highlight things in a map better.

After scrambling, you will be delighted,
But in first kill the guest on the right.

> Generally, in a treasure map, you will have to find out where the treasure is located. And once you find the location of the treasure, you will be delighted.
> And if multiple people are looking for the treasure, they will find it first. So you would have to kill the other person to get the treasure. Mostly refers to pirates / sailors.

Find the word near the burial ground,
But count only half of the numeral.
Put a spell on the word, not the sound,
 
And the answer is there, not a funeral.

> In the burial ground, the word 'X' is found denoting / marked to be dug up for a coffin / casket to be put. In the Treasure Map, it means you find the treasure buried somewhere near the place of the the marked location. So indirectly telling that you need find the first half i.e. "TREASURE" in "TREASURE MAP".

Regarding the hint:

Hint:

```
 marks the spot,
And the colour's nearly hot.
```

> This indicates that generally in maps, a cross or 'X' is marked in red colour denoting a treasure.

Comment: That is not the answer, but a very good try! I might have to add a little bit too my hint to make this riddle less broad, but otherwise, when my daily voting limit is over, $(+1)$.